# CakePHP counterCache with contain

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, containable

i have the following database structure:

**Users**

```
id, username, ..., silver_medal_counter, gold_medal_counter, bronze_medal_counter
```

**Badges**

```
id, name, description, points, medal (silver, gold, bronze)
```

**Userbadges**

```
id, user_id, badge_id, created
```

If a userbadge were added, the counterCache should update the relevant medal_counter field in the users table.

What i have:

```
class Userbadge extends AppModel {
     public $belongsTo = array(
          'User' => array(
            'counterCache' => array(
                'silver_medal_counter' => array('Userbadge.Badge.medal' => 'silver'),
                'gold_medal_counter' => array('Userbadge.Badge.medal' => 'gold'),
                'bronze_medal_counter' => array('Userbadge.Badge.medal' => 'bronze')
            )
          ),
          'Badge' => array('className' => 'Badge')
      );
}
```

*Note:* The `$actAs =  array('Containable');` is included. I am using `cakephp 2.5.6`.

How can i solve this?